# pgadmin 4, import csv, error code 1, no error message

Tags: postgresql, csv, pgadmin-4

I am trying to import csv into pgadmin4.

I keep getting an error code 1, but no details.

the command log:

```
2021-02-19 01:47:08.718 UTC [88] STATEMENT:  COPY  public.flights ( year, quarter, month, dayofmonth, dayofweek, flightdate, reporting_airline, dot_id_reporting_airline, iata_code_reporting_airline, tail_number, flight_number_reporting_airline, originairportid, originairportseqid, origincitymarketid, origin, origincityname, originstate, originstatefips, originstatename, originwac, destairportid, destairportseqid, destcitymarketid, dest, destcityname, deststate, deststatefips, deststatename, destwac, crsdeptime, deptime, depdelay, depdelayminutes, depdel15, departuredelaygroups, deptimeblk, taxiout, wheelsoff, wheelson, taxiin, crsarrtime, arrtime, arrdelay, arrdelayminutes, arrdel15, arrivaldelaygroups, arrtimeblk, cancelled, cancellationcode, diverted, crselapsedtime, actualelapsedtime, airtime, flights, distance, distancegroup, carrierdelay, weatherdelay, nasdelay, securitydelay, lateaircraftdelay, firstdeptime, totaladdgtime, longestaddgtime, divairportlandings, divreacheddest, divactualelapsedtime, divarrdelay, divdistance, div1airport, div1airportid, div1airportseqid, div1wheelson, div1totalgtime, div1longestgtime, div1wheelsoff, div1tailnum, div2airport, div2airportid, div2airportseqid, div2wheelson, div2totalgtime, div2longestgtime, div2wheelsoff, div2tailnum, div3airport, div3airportid, div3airportseqid, div3wheelson, div3totalgtime, div3longestgtime, div3wheelsoff, div3tailnum, div4airport, div4airportid, div4airportseqid, div4wheelson, div4totalgtime, div4longestgtime, div4wheelsoff, div4tailnum, div5airport, div5airportid, div5airportseqid, div5wheelson, div5totalgtime, div5longestgtime, div5wheelsoff, div5tailnum ) FROM STDIN  DELIMITER ',' CSV   HEADER  ENCODING 'UTF8' QUOTE '"' ESCAPE '''';
```

I have tried various (though i understand them and think i have the right combos):

- encoding
- header/ no header
- different quote / escape combos
- i remove the id field from the columns list, as its not in the csv

the data downloaded is a large sample, so i could imagine i need to adjust something, however i have no idea what when given no details in the error message.

Every field allows null except id.

create statement below.

```
 CREATE TABLE FLIGHTS(
ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
Year INT,
Quarter INT,
Month INT,
DayofMonth INT,
DayOfWeek INT,
FlightDate CHAR(50),
Reporting_Airline CHAR(50),
DOT_ID_Reporting_Airline CHAR(50),
IATA_CODE_Reporting_Airline CHAR(50),
Tail_Number CHAR(50),
Flight_Number_Reporting_Airline CHAR(50),
OriginAirportID CHAR(50),
OriginAirportSeqID CHAR(50),
OriginCityMarketID CHAR(50),
Origin CHAR(50),
OriginCityName CHAR(50),
OriginState CHAR(50),
OriginStateFips CHAR(50),
OriginStateName CHAR(50),
OriginWac CHAR(50),
DestAirportID CHAR(50),
DestAirportSeqID CHAR(50),
DestCityMarketID CHAR(50),
Dest CHAR(50),
DestCityName CHAR(50),
DestState CHAR(50),
DestStateFips CHAR(50),
DestStateName CHAR(50),
DestWac CHAR(50),
CRSDepTime CHAR(50),
DepTime CHAR(50),
DepDelay CHAR(50),
DepDelayMinutes CHAR(50),
DepDel15 CHAR(50),
DepartureDelayGroups CHAR(50),
DepTimeBlk CHAR(50),
TaxiOut CHAR(50),
WheelsOff CHAR(50),
WheelsOn CHAR(50),
TaxiIn INT,
CRSArrTime INT,
ArrTime INT,
ArrDelay INT,
ArrDelayMinutes INT,
ArrDel15 INT,
ArrivalDelayGroups INT,
ArrTimeBlk INT,
Cancelled INT,
CancellationCode CHAR(50),
Diverted INT,
CRSElapsedTime INT,
ActualElapsedTime INT,
AirTime INT,
Flights INT,
Distance INT,
DistanceGroup INT,
CarrierDelay INT,
WeatherDelay INT,
NASDelay INT,
SecurityDelay INT,
LateAircraftDelay INT,
FirstDepTime CHAR(50),
TotalAddGTime CHAR(50),
LongestAddGTime CHAR(50),
DivAirportLandings INT,
DivReachedDest INT,
DivActualElapsedTime INT,
DivArrDelay INT,
DivDistance INT,
Div1Airport CHAR(50),
Div1AirportID CHAR(50),
Div1AirportSeqID CHAR(50),
Div1WheelsOn CHAR(50),
Div1TotalGTime CHAR(50),
Div1LongestGTime CHAR(50),
Div1WheelsOff CHAR(50),
Div1TailNum CHAR(50),
Div2Airport CHAR(50),
Div2AirportID CHAR(50),
Div2AirportSeqID CHAR(50),
Div2WheelsOn CHAR(50),
Div2TotalGTime CHAR(50),
Div2LongestGTime CHAR(50),
Div2WheelsOff CHAR(50),
Div2TailNum CHAR(50),
Div3Airport CHAR(50),
Div3AirportID CHAR(50),
Div3AirportSeqID CHAR(50),
Div3WheelsOn CHAR(50),
Div3TotalGTime CHAR(50),
Div3LongestGTime CHAR(50),
Div3WheelsOff CHAR(50),
Div3TailNum CHAR(50),
Div4Airport CHAR(50),
Div4AirportID CHAR(50),
Div4AirportSeqID CHAR(50),
Div4WheelsOn CHAR(50),
Div4TotalGTime CHAR(50),
Div4LongestGTime CHAR(50),
Div4WheelsOff CHAR(50),
Div4TailNum CHAR(50),
Div5Airport CHAR(50),
Div5AirportID CHAR(50),
Div5AirportSeqID CHAR(50),
Div5WheelsOn CHAR(50),
Div5TotalGTime CHAR(50),
Div5LongestGTime CHAR(50),
Div5WheelsOff CHAR(50),
Div5TailNum CHAR(50));
```

Sample data:

```
"Year","Quarter","Month","DayofMonth","DayOfWeek","FlightDate","Reporting_Airline","DOT_ID_Reporting_Airline","IATA_CODE_Reporting_Airline","Tail_Number","Flight_Number_Reporting_Airline","OriginAirportID","OriginAirportSeqID","OriginCityMarketID","Origin","OriginCityName","OriginState","OriginStateFips","OriginStateName","OriginWac","DestAirportID","DestAirportSeqID","DestCityMarketID","Dest","DestCityName","DestState","DestStateFips","DestStateName","DestWac","CRSDepTime","DepTime","DepDelay","DepDelayMinutes","DepDel15","DepartureDelayGroups","DepTimeBlk","TaxiOut","WheelsOff","WheelsOn","TaxiIn","CRSArrTime","ArrTime","ArrDelay","ArrDelayMinutes","ArrDel15","ArrivalDelayGroups","ArrTimeBlk","Cancelled","CancellationCode","Diverted","CRSElapsedTime","ActualElapsedTime","AirTime","Flights","Distance","DistanceGroup","CarrierDelay","WeatherDelay","NASDelay","SecurityDelay","LateAircraftDelay","FirstDepTime","TotalAddGTime","LongestAddGTime","DivAirportLandings","DivReachedDest","DivActualElapsedTime","DivArrDelay","DivDistance","Div1Airport","Div1AirportID","Div1AirportSeqID","Div1WheelsOn","Div1TotalGTime","Div1LongestGTime","Div1WheelsOff","Div1TailNum","Div2Airport","Div2AirportID","Div2AirportSeqID","Div2WheelsOn","Div2TotalGTime","Div2LongestGTime","Div2WheelsOff","Div2TailNum","Div3Airport","Div3AirportID","Div3AirportSeqID","Div3WheelsOn","Div3TotalGTime","Div3LongestGTime","Div3WheelsOff","Div3TailNum","Div4Airport","Div4AirportID","Div4AirportSeqID","Div4WheelsOn","Div4TotalGTime","Div4LongestGTime","Div4WheelsOff","Div4TailNum","Div5Airport","Div5AirportID","Div5AirportSeqID","Div5WheelsOn","Div5TotalGTime","Div5LongestGTime","Div5WheelsOff","Div5TailNum",
2020,1,1,17,5,2020-01-17,"B6",20409,"B6","N661JB","942",14027,1402702,34027,"PBI","West Palm Beach/Palm Beach, FL","FL","12","Florida",33,10529,1052906,30529,"BDL","Hartford, CT","CT","09","Connecticut",11,"1940","1926",-14.00,0.00,0.00,-1,"1900-1959",15.00,"1941","2212",6.00,"2229","2218",-11.00,0.00,0.00,-1,"2200-2259",0.00,"",0.00,169.00,172.00,151.00,1.00,1133.00,5,,,,,,"",,,0,,,,,"",,,"",,,"","","",,,"",,,"","","",,,"",,,"","","",,,"",,,"","","",,,"",,,"","",
2020,1,1,18,6,2020-01-18,"B6",20409,"B6","N584JB","942",14027,1402702,34027,"PBI","West Palm Beach/Palm Beach, FL","FL","12","Florida",33,10529,1052906,30529,"BDL","Hartford, CT","CT","09","Connecticut",11,"1940","1926",-14.00,0.00,0.00,-1,"1900-1959",14.00,"1940","2207",13.00,"2229","2220",-9.00,0.00,0.00,-1,"2200-2259",0.00,"",0.00,169.00,174.00,147.00,1.00,1133.00,5,,,,,,"",,,0,,,,,"",,,"",,,"","","",,,"",,,"","","",,,"",,,"","","",,,"",,,"","","",,,"",,,"","",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use pgAdmin to debug this, since it hides the error message from you. You need to click "More Details..." and then expand the dialog box by dragging a corner then you'll see the error message.

With `psql`, I get:

```
ERROR:  extra data after last expected column
CONTEXT:  COPY flights, line 2: "2020,1,1,17,5,2020-01-17,"B6",20409,"B6","N661JB","942",14027,1402702,34027,"PBI","West Palm Beach/P..."
```

Indeed, there is a trailing comma at the end of each line. If I remove that comma, I get a different error message:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "6.00"
CONTEXT:  COPY flights, line 2, column taxiin: "6.00"
```

So you see, the error messages are helpful. Use `psql` to debug the problem. Once everything works, you can revert to pgAdmin.

Comment: psql `COPY` command?  thanks for the advice.

Comment: `psql` is the command line client. I used `\copy`, which calls `COPY FROM STDIN` behind the scenes.

Comment: did you ignore the `id` field by passing all the column names except it?

Comment: for those that come here, the extra column was because i added an `id` field that was not in the original data set.  my dilemma was writing out 119 columns in the \copy command or dropping the id field.  I dropped the id field, did a copy, then ran this command: `ALTER TABLE flights ADD COLUMN id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;`

Comment: pgadmin doesn't hide the error, you need to click "More Details..." and then expand the dialog box by dragging a corner then you'll see the error message.